# Accurate polygon construction for Koeppen-Geiger climate zones in Google Maps Instance

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, data-visualization, polygon, data-cleaning

I am trying to map the Koeppen-Geiger climate zones on to a Google Maps instance in my web application. Here is a link to the dataset under section Map and Data (Version June 2006):

[see file name Koeppen-Geiger-ASCII.txt](http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/present.htm)

[image: screen grab of link to data]

Below the link to txt file, you can see what the climate zones should look like. There are also gif and pdf links available to get a closer look.

I wrote a parser to get polygon paths to construct polygons to attach to my map. Here are the results for just climate zone "Dfc" when I draw the polygon:

[image: resulting polygon on map]

Not quite a solid shape. But you can make out a general outline atleast.

This is the current version of my parser written in python - parser.py:

```
# parser for koppen-geiger map coordinates files
# input is name of file
# output is one file per cz in the form of array of arrays of objects

import sys

inFile = sys.argv[1]

climate_zones = ["Af", "Am", "As", "Aw", "BWk", "BWh", "BSk", "BSh", "Cfa", "Cfb", "Cfc", "Csa", "Csb", "Csc", "Cwa", "Cwb", "Cwc", "Dfa", "Dfb", "Dfc", "Dfd", "Dsa", "Dsb", "Dsc", "Dsd", "Dwa", "Dwb", "Dwc", "Dwd", "EF", "ET"]

def parse(cz):
    outFile = f'{sys.argv[1][0:-4]}_{cz}.js'

    with open(inFile, 'r') as inf, open(outFile, 'w') as outf:

        outf.write("export default [")
        outf.write('\n')
        active_zone = False

        for line in inf:
            line = line.split()

            if cz == line[2]:
                if not active_zone:
                    outf.write("[\n")
                active_zone = True
            else:
                if active_zone:
                    outf.write("],\n")
                active_zone = False
            if active_zone:
                output_line = "{" + f'lat: {line[0]}, lng: {line[1]}' + "},"
                outf.write(output_line)
                outf.write('\n')
        
        outf.write("]")

for zone in climate_zones:
    parse(zone)
```

Here are steps to reproduce:

1. Download the text file linked to above [Koeppen-Geiger-ASCII.txt]
2. Make sure to delete the top two lines of the txt file which denote the columns (for the parser).
3. From terminal - run the parser.py script with the txt file name as a command line argument which will generate one javascript file per climate zone. File exports an array of arrays, since separate polygons can be part of the same climate zone. The Maps JS API allows for separately drawn shapes to be part of the same polygon object instance.
4. Follow this tutorial on how to get a google maps instance into a web application (Google Cloud billing account is required):
   [Maps JS API overview](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#all)
5. Follow this tutorial on how to attach a Google Maps instance to a polygon:
   [Adding polygon to Google Maps instance](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygon_add)
6. Import the JavaScript file for the climate zone coordinates generated by the parser and replace the triangleCoords array from tutorial with the new array. Pick any of the 20 or so js files for each climate zone. Some files yield more chaotic results than others.

So I am thinking the ordering of the lat lng pairs in the datafile has something to do with this issue. I can't identify what the pattern is, but ideally I have one single path outline for each separate shape for each climate zone.

Comment: The [data](http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/present.htm) doesn't seem to be available

Comment: There is a link to a zip file @geocodezip under the heading MAP AND DATA (VERSION JUNE 2006) where the txt file can be found. I've edited the question to show a screen grab of the link.

Comment: It wasn't working reliably for me, I think I have a copy of it now.

Comment: hey @geocodezip any luck with the problem?

Comment: What does the output javascript data for the polygons look like?

Comment: Looks like the parser is adding too many "[" & "]" breaking the big polygon into lots of small ones.

Comment: yes that is by design - if you look at the actual climate zones in the page for the dataset, you see that climate zones them selves have many seperate areas, and therefore different polygons. for example the climate zone Dfc is found in both Russia and Canada.

But maybe instead of creating a single Gmaps polygon instance - with disconnected graphs, I can create separate polygon instances for each separate area for each separate climate zone. I will need to update parser for that.

Comment: You have single point polygon paths in the output data, I wouldn't think that would be correct.  It is possible that there isn't enough information in that file to reconstruct the polygons.